# Is there way to define numeric-like enums in avdl file

Tags: java, avro

I know about "normal" avro enums which are defined by

```
enum ActionType {CREATE, REMOVE}
```

in .avdl file
or via this type of construction in avro schema:

```
{ "type": "enum",
  "name": "ActionType",
  "symbols" : ["CREATE", "REMOVE"]
}
```

Problem is that my specific entity will have field that can have values
"01" and "02".

So my questions are:
1. Is this correct avro enum definition

```
{ "type": "enum",
  "name": "MyType",
  "symbols" : ["01", "02"]
}
```

or I'll have to choose simple

```
{"name":"id","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}}
```

2. Is there way to write such enum in avdl file(I prefer to use avro-maven-plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, unfortunately that is not a valid Avro schema. The spec states that the first character of a symbol must be an a-z or underscore. Note the part about the symbol matching a regular expression.

> symbols: a JSON array, listing symbols, as JSON strings (required). All symbols in an enum must be unique; duplicates are prohibited. Every symbol must match the regular expression `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*` (the same requirement as for names).

https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Enums

2. Since the answer to #1 is no, the answer to #2 is no, you cannot define a valid enum in which a symbol begins with a number.

You may want to consider a sort of transform layer that transforms raw values "01", "02" to/from Avro enum symbols "VALUE_01", "VALUE_02". That would have to be defined in you application code. It is not functionality provided by Avro. Alternatively, you could define this as a `string` like you suggested. That would probably be the quickest solution, but does not explicitly define and limit possible values like an enum does.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped that I haven't noticed some workaround. Then I'll go for string